# Uploading a file

Tags: html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement file upload progress bar on web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564/how-to-implement-file-upload-progress-bar-on-web)

Hello

I have seen many webpages where the user is able to upload a file and he is given some sort of progress as visual feedback (horizontal bar, percentage etc).

My html form is

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="selected_file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload the file"></p>
</form>
```

How can I provide the user with a feed during the upload?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at very good:

[UBER-UPLOADER 6.8.2](http://www.webdice.org/uber_uploader/)

Answer (score 2):

there are many javascript and flash scripts out there which provide such a option.

my favorite one is [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php).
it supports html5 as well as flash and many others to choose from

see the [examples](http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php) and [documentation](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaSqript.
For e.g. i suggest to see http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/php-jquery-image-upload-and-crop/

Answer (score 0):

for your purpose you can use **uploadify**. its a jquery upload plugin. the link to uploadify is http://www.uploadify.com/. the link to its demo page is http://www.uploadify.com/demo/.

its easy to use. and it have good documentation too. try this