# Upload progress using javascript only

Tags: javascript, file-upload, progress-bar

Is it possible to make a upload progress using javascript only? (maybe with some ajax to a server-side code)

Having a form such as

```
<form method="post" action="upload.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="selected_file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload the file"></p>
<div id="progress"></div>
</form>
```

I want to display things as upload progress, speed, total size.

I don't want tools for it, I want to understand how it is done without flash, and **from scratch**.

Similar questions (none from scratch):

- [Uploading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245345/uploading-a-file)
- [How to implement file upload progress bar on web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564/how-to-implement-file-upload-progress-bar-on-web)
- [Upload progress using pure PHP/AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653063/upload-progress-using-pure-php-ajax)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload progress using pure PHP/AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653063/upload-progress-using-pure-php-ajax)

Comment: Just a brief idea on how it is done and where I could search for resources would be enough. I am just curious about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now what you mean by "from scratch". I know of no way to do this  that doesn't require some server-side fiddling.

If you have access to PHP 5.2 and can install additional modules, I think this is the closest you'll get regarding a step-by-step process:

[What's new in PHP V5.2, Part 5: Tracking file upload progress](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-v525/index.html)

It requires APC but as I said, there is no "pure" PHP / Ajax solution as far as I know.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849237/upload-progress-bar-in-php) contains a number of additional interesting resources.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is your friend. In particular, you should read up on **File API specifications of HTML5** (**w3.org/TR/FileAPI/**). In brief, it's done with the help of **FileReader** interface. Googling might suggest a read such as this one at **matlus.com/2010/09/html5-file-upload-with-progress/**. Also, there are some limits of the API atm and you might want to learn about those from **hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/html5-adoption-stories-box-net-and-html5-drag-and-drop/**.